# How can I position buttons, labels and images in kivy so that they resize?

Tags: python, kivy

I am new to programming and I challenged myself to code a wordle app for IOS. I finished the logical part, but I am now stuck with the design of the app. I figured out how to position the buttons and labels on my screen, but the issue is when I try to resize the window, it does not adjust the position of the buttons.

This adds buttons and labels to the window:
[image]

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) addressing your main problem.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Have a look at [size_hint](https://kivy.org/doc/stable-2.0.0/api-kivy.uix.layout.html#understanding-the-size-hint-property-in-widget).